# How can you count how many swaps bubble sort will perform?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, bubble-sort

http://www.codechef.com/problems/LEBOBBLE

Bubble sorting for any array A of n integers works in the following way:

```
var int i, j; 
for i from n downto 1 
{ 
  for j from 1 to i-1 
  { 
    if (A[j] > A[j+1]) 
    swap(A[j], A[j+1]) 
  } 
}
```

You are given an array B of n integers.

Then the array A is created using array B as following : 
for each i (1 <= i <= n), we set Ai = Bi + d with the probability Pi, otherwise Ai = Bi.
Help Little Elephant to find the expect number of swaps that bubble sorting will make when the array A is sorted with the above bubble sorting algorithm.
Input

First line of the input contains single integer T - the number of test cases. T test cases follows. First line of each test case contains pair of integers n and d. Next line of each test case contains n integers - array B. Next line contains n integers - array P.
Output In T lines print T real numbers - the answers for the corresponding test case. Please round all numbers to exactly 4 digits after decimal point.
Constraint

```
1 <= T <= 5
1 <= n <= 50000
1 <= Bi, d <= 10^9
0 <= Pi, <= 100
Example

Input:
2
2 7
4 7
50 50
4 7
5 6 1 7
25 74 47 99

Output:
0.2500
1.6049
```

Do you have any hints about how to approach this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You will have a better chance of getting help with your problem if you provide a sample of the work you have done so far and ask questions specific to the exact problem you are having.

Comment: So to clarify, is what you're trying to find the number of swaps required for a specific input, or the number of swaps on average(computational complexity)?

Comment: title is a desaster...

Comment: do the problem step by step, try first sorting an array of 4 integers and work your way up to the final stage

Answer (score 2):

As a hint - the number of swaps made in bubble sort is equal to the number of [inversions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_%28discrete_mathematics%29) in the array.  There is a famous divide-and-conquer algorithm to compute the number of inversions in an array in time O(n log n) - can you figure out how to do this?

Hope this helps!